# Symfony2 textarea ignores trim options

Tags: forms, symfony-2.3

I need all the whitespaces in a textarea. I set the trim option to false but it seems that it's totally ignoring it.

```
$builder->add('descr', 'textarea', array(
    'trim' => false
));
```

[About textarea's trim option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/textarea.html#trim)

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I possibly have a solution for those, who face a similar issue.

The problem isn't the ignored 'trim' attribute.

The html simply doesn't render \n as a line break.

Try following in your .twig file:

```
{{ entity.descr|nl2br }}
```

This converts \n to `<br>`.

Source: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/nl2br.html

Hope, this helps.

Comment: the problem is that the submitted data is trimmed. always. so when I start typing with two new lines (I press two enters) those empty line are gone after the form is submitted. I need them too...